# $c$-dense set with perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A set  $D\subset\mathbb R$ is called continuum dense if $|D\cap(a,b)|=c$ ($c$ is cardinality of $\mathbb R$) for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $a<b.$ Let $P\subset\mathbb R$ be perfect set (uncountable closed set without isolated set). How about $$D\cap P \ ?$$  can be empty set ? what is the cardinality?  Any will be appreciated greatly

Comment: Let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set; it’s perfect, and $\Bbb R\setminus C$ is continuum dense, so the intersection can be empty.

Comment: Brain, I forgot about this case. Thank so much

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing nontrivial we can say.

Removing a nowhere-dense set won't affect the "density character" of a given set. In particular, if we let $C$ be a perfect nowhere-dense set (e.g. the usual Cantor set) then $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is still continuum-dense but of course $C\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus C)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Noah, I forgot about this case. Thank so much